# Обрыв соединения при отправки запроса. ECONNRESET

Tags: node.js, requests, postman

Задача: просто послать запрос авторизации и получить ответ. Запрос POST с данными. Node JS постоянно выдает ошибку ECONNRESET. А вот PostMan работает как нужно. Я сделал копию запроса Postman в Node JS, но ошибка осталась.
Код Node JS:

```
const request = require('request');

var cookieJar = request.jar();
var options = {
    url: `http://10.47.2.32/login.cgi`,
    timeout: 40000,
    jar: cookieJar,
    form: { "username": 'root', "passwd": 'root'},
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.24.1',
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Postman-Token': '471124c1-c1e7-40ca-a8db-58292496c72e'
    }
}

request.post(options, (error, response, body) => {
      console.log(error);
      console.log(response);
      console.log(body);
      if (error) console.log(`Error: ${error.code} !`);
   })
```

Ответ:

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:205:27) {
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
undefined
undefined
Error: ECONNRESET !
```

Теперь скриншот из Wareshark. Слева PostMan, Справа NodeJS

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот скриншот Wareshark:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите понять почему 2 одинаковых запроса так обрабатываются?

Comment: есть исходник login.cgi? есть возможность читать логи сервиса? ошибка появляется сразу или через 40секунд?

Comment: @nörbörnën, исходника нет. На сервер тоже доступа нет. Ошибка появляется мгновенно.